# Instagram Video not loaded properly loaded in Drupal 7 on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, drupal, drupal-7

I have an article running in Drupal 7. The content's Embedded Video from instagram didn't load fully and the content after video isn't display on iPhone.

Tested on iPad & Desktop seem fine. it's only have problem in iPhone as this  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AazK0.png).

Appreciate if you guys have any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It's causing because of height issue. So change the following css to fix issue.

```
html {
height: 100%;}
```

to

```
html {
/*height: 100%;*/}
```